# Installing Android sdk into xamarin

Tags: android, installation, xamarin

I have installed Xamarin version 4.0.8 and I have to install and add Android sdk, you know I downloaded Android (adt-bundle-windows-x86) and I have an Installer (installer_r22-windows.exe). Anybody can tell me please what I can use for install Android sdk into Xamarin ?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use the older version of Xamarin? I was playing with such things before, and the best solution that I found it to install the latest version of Xamarin, it will download and install all needed for android. Then I uninstalled latest version of Xamarin (but it will keep android sdk) and installed the needed one

Comment: Yes ,  4.0.8 is not a new version, I need to install Android sdk